How to make sure the "background"（watermark）is only for the first page when using pdfpages to include a pdf?
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme = plain]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%%% \usepackage{draftwatermark}
%%% \SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
%%% \SetWatermarkScale{1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\backgroundsetup{
    firstpage= true,
    scale    = 1, 
    angle    = 0, 
    opacity  = 0.2,
    contents = { \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{example-image} }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{./path_to_a_file}
\clearpage
\end{document}

I wish to include some "watermark"(background) to some pdf files, only on the first pages.
A small example is given above, but the firstpage= true does not seem to be working...
Any ideas? I think something in \includepdf[pages=-]{./path_to_a_file} should be changed, but I am not sure how.

The firstpage=true option only says to include the background on the first page; it doesn't impact whether backgrounds are printed on subsequent pages. By default background prints the background on all pages; to make it only print on some pages, pass it the pages=some option.
MWE (note, I use article instead of ctexart, but it shouldn't make a difference):
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%%% \usepackage{draftwatermark}
%%% \SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
%%% \SetWatermarkScale{1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\backgroundsetup{
    firstpage= true,
    scale    = 1, 
    angle    = 0, 
    opacity  = 0.2,
    contents = { \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{example-image} }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{./test.pdf}
\clearpage
\end{document}

Note According to the package manual all options can be used in \backgroundsetup and as options to \usepackage; but my tests seems to indicate that pages is ignored in \backgroundsetup
Note Incidentally, with both pages=all (the default) and firstpage=true, it seems that the package prints the background twice on the first page, resulting in (since you set a opacity < 1) an extra dark background on that page.
